# MiniMagick::Error failed:

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, editor, redactor

I install Redactor-rails ruby gem with instructions from official page on github [SammyLin/redactor-rails](https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails)
, all it's ok, but when I'm trying to upload image I have error like this:

Started POST "/redactor_rails                                                          /pictures?authenticity_token=aRAR6p4FMDNmdh%2FgqP24kYSIo0CWXjnEgYGBli%2FjcX8%3D" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-17 20:34:34 +0400
Processing by RedactorRails::PicturesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"file"=>#>, "authenticity_token"=>"aRAR6p4FMDNmdh/gqP24kYSIo0CWXjnEgYGBli/jcX8="}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 134 LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 611ms

MiniMagick::Error (Command ("identify -quiet -ping -format %wn /home/igor/rubycode/badm.by/public/uploads/tmp/1374078874-9075-4230/***_*__*_*____**_2013-05-19_22_58_40.png") failed: {:status_code=>127, :output=>"sh: 1: identify: not found\n"}):

Explain me please why I have this error, i google I've found nothing about this error.

Comment: +1 because I am not sure why this question was even downvoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue. Just install the ImageMagick package on your system.

e.g. for Ubuntu,

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Answer (score 0):

what uploader are you using? i suggest you use carrierwve gem, and here are the isntructions for it:

```
gem "carrierwave"
gem "mini_magick"

$ rails generate redactor:install

or

$ rails generate redactor:install --devise

# --devise option generate user_id attribute for asset(Picture, Document) models. For more details show Devise gem.
# Now, Pictures and Documents uploading available only for signed in users
# All uploaded files will stored with current user_id
# User will choose only own uploaded Pictures and Documents

$ rake db:migrate
```

Comment: I install with this instructions, and install carrierwave,too

Comment: What mean  works as a standalone standalone? I add this gem to Gemfile, and that is all.

Comment: can you upload an image, try folowwing this cast to get carrierwaeve to work: http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

Comment: Ok, thank you for a link. I've watched this episod, but Redactor-rails create upload directory with file `redactor_rails_document_uploader.rb` and `redactor_rails_picture_uploader.rb` automatically. Or I must create, for form that I want to change, column as image and image_url how author did in this cast?

Comment: im pretty sure that when you run this command: rails generate redactor:install, and later migrate the database with rake db:migrate it will create the folders